# how to put a webhostdatabase connection string in a winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, web-hosting

i have myself tried a lot but i couldn't find out what is the problem of my below connection string. i have put both my webhost connection string and winform connection string help please?

```
<connectionStrings> <add name="ReGdbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
initial catalog=ReGdb;
integrated security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

and here is my webhostdatabase connectionstring

```
Data Source=SQL5000322.Smarterasp.net;
Initial Catalog=DB_9BDB7789_ReGdb;
User Id=DB_9BDB7789_ReGdb_admin;
Password=happy;
```

Comment: do not post passwords here (the NSA is reading this,,,)

Comment: @DrKoch appreciate your advice, but this is not a real password.

Comment: better to use something obvious like "****" to silent the alarm bells in heads of people reading this

Comment: that was good comment, you are right, good for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey bro you can modify your connection string this way and it must work. just copy and replace it with your connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ReGdbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection tring=quot;
datasource=SQL5000322.Smarterasp.net;
initial catalog=DB_9BDB7789_ReGdb;
User Id=DB_9BDB7789_ReGdb_admin;
Password=happy;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

here you go bro it must work

Comment: `tring=quot`--> `string=&quot`

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to nested quotes:

```
provider connection string=&quot;data source=...
```

Comment: that was not the case, appreciated.